# Why does \cal{M}_n give “M>”?

Tags: symbols

Why does `\cal{M}_n` give “M>” in parts of my LaTeX file and works correctly in other parts?

[image]

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The correct syntax is

```
$\mathcal{C}_n$
```

The `\cal` command was used in LaTeX 2.09 and has been obsolete since the release of LaTeX2e (1992). It worked as a *font change declaration* rather than a command with argument, so the right way would have been

```
${\cal C}_n$
```

which is quite confusing.

Note, however, that `\mathcal{C_n}` would give the same result as `\cal C_n`, because (were it not because `\mathcal` is not actually defined in terms of `\cal`, which is deprecated) we might think to `\mathcal{...}` as `{\cal ...}`.

Comment: I've heard that some obsolete commands are nice in latex like (over for fraction). Does this mean I should never use obsolete commands or is this (`\cal`) a special case?

Comment: @CharlieParker It's best to use the “official” commands. The usage of `\cal` in this case was wrong to begin with; the result would have been the same with LaTeX2.09.