# math after some font will change

Tags: fonts

I have trouble when I use the command \cal{B} , sometime the content after this command  will be change to arrow or triangle or similar unwanted symbol . this is the code:-

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\cal{B}=(b_i)$
\end{document}
```

any help appricated

Comment: Same question here:
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84041/why-does-calm-n-give-m

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84041/why-does-calm-n-give-m. Your problem is that `\cal` is an obsolete switch, which means that it's used like `\bfseries` and formats the entire environment unless you enclose it in braces like so: `{\cal B}`. `\cal{B}` does what `\bfseries{B}` or `\bf{B}` does in the main text. As a result, the `\cal` font is applied to everything and it has glyphs such as arrows encoded in various positions for ease of input, much like old non-roman fonts used to remap ASCII, so you'd type `a` and get, I dunno, `अ`. Use `\mathcal{B}` for correct results