# LaTeX \mathcal{w} has strange printout

Tags: mathcal

The follwing LaTex lines don't print out what I hope to see:

```
calculate $\rho_i^{t} = \| \mathcal{w}_{i}^{t} - \mathcal{w}_{i}^{t-1} \|_2$
```

what I get instead of the two w is that:

[image: see here]

Can anyone help me please?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Very similar question: [symbols - Why does \cal{M}_n give “M>”? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84041/why-does-calm-n-give-m?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's because the font does not have lowercase characters.  This is also documented in the TeXbook (in plain TeX you get the effect of `\mathcal` using `\cal`).

> For example, ‘`$\cal A$`’ produces ‘‘ and ‘`$\cal Z$`‘ produces ‘’. But beware: This works only with the letters `A` to `Z`; you'll get weird results if you apply `\cal` to lowercase or Greek letters.

As you can see from the symbols table below, there are other characters encoded in the slots where lowercase usually is (`w` maps to slot 119).

[image]

---

That being said, some Unicode math fonts have a lowercase script alphabet, e.g. XITS Math.  The Unicode version of Latin Modern unfortunately does not have a lowercase script alphabet.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}
\begin{document}
$\rho_i^{t} = \| \mathscr{w}_{i}^{t} - \mathscr{w}_{i}^{t-1} \|_2$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wonderful, thank you. I used now \mathit{w}. Looks also pretty satisfactorily.

Comment: @FelixLaumann Instead of `\mathit{w}` you can also just use plain `w`.  The font should be the same.  The only difference is that `\mathit` enables character kerning (compare `\mathit{ff}` and `ff`), i.e. it is to be used for actual words.

Comment: @HenriMenke or rather `\mathit` is wrong, it uses the text italic font (so multi-letter identifiers work) w on its own will use math italic (which typically has wider sidebearings, and potentially different character shapes)