# Incorrect Usage of \mathcal and \mathbb Leads to Interesting Symbols

Tags: fonts, mathcal, mathbb

I noticed that some incorrect usage of the \mathcal and \mathbb command generates interesting symbols.

```
\mathcal{M^1} \mathcal{M^2} \mathcal{M^3} \mathcal{M^4} \mathcal{M^5}
```

[image: Interesting symbols]

and

```
\mathbb{M^1} \mathbb{M^2} \mathbb{M^3} \mathbb{M^4} \mathbb{M^5}
```

[image: Interesting symbols]

Is this an expected behaviour? It seems that this is not what should be expected. I am wondering why would this happen instead of an error being thrown?

Comment: Probably you're seeing the glyphs that the font has in the slots for the numbers...

Comment: Yes: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/428214/38080 (1 is in the slot 49, etc...)

Comment: The fonts for `\mathcal` and `\mathbb` (which are provided only as uppercase alphabets) contain other symbols packed in to fill the fonts.  So only the actual argument of either of those commands should be in braces: `\mathcal{M}^1`.  (Yes, a duplicate.)

Comment: The short answer (see the links in the comments above for the long answer): `\mathcal` and `\mathbb` select a different font, where regular characters such as M but also 1 are mapped to various symbols. The numbers-mapped-to-symbols are usually not entered directly, but called using macros such as `\infty`, which is internally defined as `\mathchar"231`, where 2 is the family and 31 is the hexadecimal code for the character `1`.