# Why does putting a digit under \mathcal{...} display an unrelated symbol?

Tags: math-fonts

I have found, unintentionally, that if you write

`$\mathcal{P_1}$`

you obtain the same as

`$\mathcal{P}_{\infty}$`
, i.e.,

[image]

Is this a bug or a Latex functionality unknown to me?

Comment: it is user error. `\mathcal` should only be used with captial letters. If you use anything else you get whatever symbols happen to be in those positions in the font

Comment: It's the same problem as in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/84041/4427.

Comment: It’s a bug that users invested in TeX will insist should not be fixed.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is not a bug or feature in LaTeX, it is user error. `\mathcal` should only be used with capital letters. If you use anything else you get whatever symbols happen to be in those positions in the font

See `texdoc encguide`.  `\mathcal` is documented to work with only uppercase letters for classic tex math fonts. Technically it switches to the OMS encoded symbol font which has this layout:
[image]

As you will see A-Z positions have A-Z calligraphic, but all other slots have math symbols unrelated to the ASCII positions.

Answer (score 5):

Just out of interest, I notice that using `unicode-math` changes the output here.  Using `xelatex` or `lualatex`, I find that if I compile the (incorrect) OP example, I get:

[image]

as shown in the question, but if I add `unicode-math`, like this:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}
$\mathcal{P_1}$
\end{document}
```

the output is

[image]

which is the same if I correct it to `$\mathcal{P}_1$`.